# Find distinct values from the generated result set in SQL

Tags: sql

Two select statements union together with multiple inner joins. 
Just need to find out the distinct elements out of this result sets.

I could have write distinct when selecting columns but this is not what I want.

```
SELECT 
    employeeid, employeename 
FROM   
    employee AS emp        
INNER JOIN 
    department AS dep ON emp.employeeid = dep.employeeid        
INNER JOIN 
    company AS comp ON emp.companyid = comp.companyid 

UNION 

SELECT 
    employeeid, employeename 
FROM   
    employer AS emp        
INNER JOIN 
    category AS cat ON emp.employeeid = cat.employeeid        
INNER JOIN 
    business AS busi ON emp.companyid = busi.companyid
```

Comment: "*this is not what i want*" Then what do you want

Comment: post datas ,queries  and expected output

Comment: `union` (as opposed to `union all`) already removes duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, employeename 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       employeeid, employeename 
    FROM   
       employee AS emp        
    INNER JOIN 
       department AS dep ON emp.employeeid = dep.employeeid        
    INNER JOIN 
       company AS comp ON emp.companyid = comp.companyid 

    UNION 

    SELECT 
       employeeid, employeename 
    FROM   
       employer AS emp        
    INNER JOIN 
       category AS cat ON emp.employeeid = cat.employeeid        
    INNER JOIN 
       business AS busi ON emp.companyid = busi.companyid  
) AS t
```